# HTML not changed after automatically downloading a file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, http-headers, download

I am trying to show a success message after a file is automatically downloaded on a button click(after PostBack). The code is :

```
divMessage.InnerHtml = "Your download should start automatically. If it doesn't, click <a alt='" +
                                       DownloadObject.Title + "' href='" +  DownloadObject.Url + "' target='_blank'>here</a>";
divMessage.Attributes.Add("class", "alert alert-success");



//Start downloading the file automatically
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + downloadableFileUrl.TrimStart('/'));

Response.TransmitFile(DownloadObject.Url);
Response.End();
```

Nothing happens to the HTMl but the file is successfully downloaded. Is there any workaround to display a success message in the UI?